# How to connect ACLs with protected resources?

Tags: security, spring-security, acl

What is the best way to connect an ACL with the protected resource?

1) Should the protected resource hold a reference to its ACL?

```
interface AclHolder {
    Acl getAcl();
}
```

This would be simple, but if the object lives in a database it has to be constructed before it is possible to check access rights.

2) Spring Security uses a mechanism with the fully qualified class name and the object id to attach and retrieve the ACL externally. This could lead to an n+1 select problem, because multiple ACLs cannot be selected by a certain criterion. This system could break if class names change while refactoring.

3) Another way could be to store a reference to the protected resource within the ACL. With lazy loading it would be possible to check the ACL without loading the protected resource from the database.

```
class Acl<T> {
    @Lazy public T protectedResource;
    // acl methods ...
}
```

4) Each object could have a security descriptor (like in windows):

```
class SecurityDescriptor<T> {
  public Acl acl;
  @Lazy public T protectedResource;
  // ...
}
```

What is better?

**Provisional Solution:** I will implement the AclHolder interface since domain objects can implement it and it is also possible to attach ACLs without affecting the domain objects.

Comment: I was wondering if you ever got this working?  I am implementing the very same thing (e.g. my own ACL service) and am contemplating the same choices.  One question I have is how do you protect your service mthods? Annotations?  AOP?  or traditional code at the beginning of every service method.  

Any additional lessons learned?

Answer (score 0):

spring security acl implementation comes with caching inbuilt and once that cache is warmed , the way u r going to retrieve the acl is mostly for a given object instance if u enforce the implementation through spring-security annotations, thus u dont really  hit n+1 problem and moreover it is jdbc based.
The changing of domain object class names could be an issue though , but here also the acl_class table is stores the class identities and should be reasonably small to manage it as refactoring of that level happens between major releases in a production system. Spring-security acl implementation is a reasonable choice to have a quick acl implementation in a non-intrusive way(i.e ur domain models remain agnostic of security which is primarily an application layer concern).